# Cell renderer does not format time stamps

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jodatime, tablecellrenderer

Why the following `CellRenderer` does not format time stamps? Instead of `HH:mm` I receive something strage, e.g. `07:00.000.00`

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer cellRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() 
{
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean
                                                    isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column );
        if ( value instanceof LocalDateTime )
        {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
            String strTime = formatter.print((LocalDateTime)value);
            this.setText(strTime);
        }

        return this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe `value` is not a `LocalDateTime`. Then `super.getTableCellRendererComponent(...)`will be called alone. You should check the type.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild: yep, it's instance of LocalTime. Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 2):

How did you add the renderer to the table? You need to either:

1. Specifically add the renderer to the TableColumn
2. Override the getColumnClass(...) method to return LocalDateTime.class so that your renderer will be used for any columns containing LocalDateTime objects.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information.